# Django : Configuration emails

Tags: django

It's in my settings.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yahoo.fr'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "myusername@yahoo.fr"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "myusername@yahoo.fr"
```

My commands:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('sss','hhh','myusername@outlook.fr',['myusername@yahoo.fr'])
```

The error:

```
...
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Why?
I'm not sure that I have good configured my settings.py, if you can also help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the email password to settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my email account password'
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! I have added this, and I configure the application password of my Gmail account and it's works ! But now I have a very big problem with my system using 'send_mail', I explain this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702434/send-mail-to-user-for-password-reset